# iOS fastlane deliver metadata

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I'm trying to configure `deliver` to send up my metadata for my app...

Following the screenshot here https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/deliver#readme

Specifically this one... [image]

I have created my metadata folder...

[image]

However, when I first uploaded with `fastlane deliver` it didn't do several things.

It didn't add the app icon, it did add the marketing URL, the categories etc...

I added them manually myself on iTC and then today I've done another upload from `fastlane deliver` and it removed all that data again.

I have tried to find how to configure this stuff but the documentation is lacking (literally, this screenshot is all I have found).

For example... how should I upload the app icon? The content of the `app_icon.txt` file is `./fastlane/metadata/appicon.png`. But I'm not sure where that path should be relative to?

The contents of the `marketing_url.txt` is `http://thewebsite.com` but that gets removed on each upload. But the `copyright.txt` works.

Is there somewhere I can see examples of what this data looks like?

The categories are also removed on each upload but I don't know what the text should be there? I have just got the name of the category (i.e. `Health & Fitness`) Is that wrong?

Any help or preferably a link to some docs would be very helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to get started with a correct metadata directory structure is to delete the metadata folder and the Deliverfile and run `fastlane deliver init`.

For the app icon, you'll have to provide a path to the file you want to use: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/deliver/Deliverfile.md#app_icon

Answer (score 5):

Actually, fastlane deliver works like Git. Before you execute "fastlane deliver", you should download metadata everytime using this code:

```
fastlane deliver download_metadata\
    --username ${user_name}\
    --app_identifier ${bundle_id}\
    --force true
```

Only then you can modify your metadata and execute "fastlane deliver", just like "git pull" and "git push".

Comment: Why is this necessary? And is this documented some where?